# SUM row with multiple VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

hope you can help me out!

I have a first sheet with the following information:

```
a 3
b 3
c 4
d 10
```

Then I have another sheet with the following information:

```
John a a c d
Joe  b d d c
```

I would like to display a sum of the values in front of those rows, considering the first sheet values. So it would display:

```
John a a c d 20
Joe  b d d c 27
```

Don't know how to do this exactly. would love your help. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this array formula,

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B$2:B$5, A$2:A$5, E2:H2))
```

Enter it with ctrl+shift+enter, not just enter.

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much for such a fast answer!